# Convolving a histogram with a kernel

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have some raw histogram driven out of a discrete dataset. In order to make it smooth, I have been told to convolve it with a kernel (ex. a Gaussian or a Hamming one) which values sum up to one.
Now the question is,what actually is a kernel ?And what should sum up to one and why?Is this a simple filtering using a Gaussian function?How should I implement this in MATLAB?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this in matlab `x = randn(1,1000); h = 1-cos(2*pi*[1:10]/10); h = h/sum(h); y = conv(x,h); y2 = conv(y,h); plot([x;y(1:1000);y2(1:1000)]');`. If your histogram is not linearly sampled, it will be a little more complicated (see kernel density estimation).

Comment: In this case, the kernel is set of filter coefficients that you convolve the histogram with, so it is these coefficients that should sum to one. Keep in mind that the term "kernel" has other meanings in other fields (e.g., algebra).